# how to implement RoR many-to-many relationship?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
Technician
- id
- name
- personal_id

Tool
- id
- internal_code
- name
- category
```

A technician can have many tools and one tool can be assigned to many technician (do I really need many-to-many relationship, as I'm typing this I have my doubts). My problem is that I also need to track the quantity of the tool that the technician have under his possession. One record should be like [technician_id, tool_id, quantity]. I have read about the has_many through, but i have not seen an example that fit my problem, what should the structure of the resulting table and also how should I set up the model for tools under the technician possession?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a many-to-many association here.
This should work for you given the requirements you set:

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :tools, :through => :assignments
end

class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :technicians, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tool
  belongs_to :technician
end
```

Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE**

Thinking about your comment about having a quantity field in `Assignments`, I'm assuming you are wanting to be able to assign many of the same `Tool` to a `Technician`.  For example:

```
>> Technician.new(:name => "Bob").save
=> true
>> Tool.new(:name => "hammer").save
=> true
>> Tool.new(:name => "saw").save
=> true
>> t = Technician.first
=> #<Technician id: 1, name: "Bob", personal_id: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:53", updated_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:53">
>> t.tools << [Tool.first, Tool.last]
=> [#<Tool id: 1, name: "hammer", internal_code: nil, category: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:22", updated_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:22">, #<Tool id: 2, name: "saw", internal_code: nil, category: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:30", updated_at: "2011-07-07 22:56:30">]
>> t.save
=> true
>> t.assignments
=> [#<Assignment id: 1, technician_id: 1, tool_id: 1, quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 23:01:53", updated_at: "2011-07-07 23:01:53">, #<Assignment id: 2, technician_id: 1, tool_id: 2, quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 23:02:46", updated_at: "2011-07-07 23:02:46">]
>> a = t.assignments.first
=> #<Assignment id: 1, technician_id: 1, tool_id: 1, quantity: nil, created_at: "2011-07-07 23:01:53", updated_at: "2011-07-07 23:01:53">
>> a.quantity = 5
=> 5
>> a.save
=> true
>> t.assignments.first.quantity
=> 5
>>
```

If this is not the case, let me know & I can update with another approach.

Comment: hhhm.. this would work in the case that Assignment only have technician_id and tool_id... would that work if the Assignment table also had a quantity field?

Comment: That is the benefit of `has_many :through` over `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you can have as many fields as you wish in the join model.

Comment: I will test this once I get home, will keep you posted.

Comment: This is not really the 'rails way' though. It may work, but why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Matthew Honestly, it depends on the actual use case - there may be an appropriate reason to go this way.  It's hard to tell exactly what OP is looking to accomplish at this point.

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to accomplish, assign many of the same tool to a technical, like assigning 2 hammers to a technician, sorry that I didn't reply earlier, I'm testing will update this post soon.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much, now I have to find a way to display this in my view in a convenient way. Thanks Brian.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this is the perfect place to use a HABTM relationship type. You'll want to do the following:

Run the following migration:

```
class AddTechniciansToolsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :technicians_tools, :id => false  do |t|
      t.integer :technician_id, :null => :false
      t.integer :tool_id, :null => :false
    end
    add_index :technicians_tools, [:technician_id, :tools_id], :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :technicians_tools
  end
end
```

Add the following to your models:

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tools
end

class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :technicians
end
```

This will allow you to use a number of Rails methods which are specific to a HABTM relationship such as `technician.tools.size` for a count of the tools available to that specific technician.

For more info, have a look at the Rails guides about HABTM relationships here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference

Comment: Let's say you did `technician = Technician.find(params[:id])` and then `technician.tools.size` the count would give you the number of tools related to that specific technician object. I believe that's what you're looking for?