# How to Nest Models within a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, one-to-many

Imagine I have two models

```
Film
-name
-description
-duration
-year_made
-rating
-actors

Actor
-name
-d_o_b
-biography
-films
```

Actors are nested in a Film and vice versa.

How do I represent this relationship in my Ruby models? Realistically I would have a third table mapping `actor_id` with `film_id`.

Whilst adding details to a film I would like to be able to create an actor on the fly(if an actor does not exist create a new one with the name supplied)

Thank you in advance.

**ADDITION**:

Just found a link to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617778/how-to-implement-ror-many-to-many-relationship/6617955#6617955).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at a Has and Belongs to Many (HABTM) relationship between the two tables.
Read about HABTM relationship in the Rails guides here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference

First you'll need to generate a migration which will look something like this:

```
class AddActorFilmTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :actors_films, :id => false  do |t|
      t.integer :actor_id, :null => :false
      t.integer :film_id, :null => :false
    end
    add_index :actors_films, [:actor_id, :film_id], :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :actors_films
  end
end
```

and then specify in your models:

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :films
end

class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :actors
end
```

This will allow you to use all of the additional Rails methods for this type of relationship. To use this in a form, you could follow [RailsCast 17: HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) - though it's old, it should still apply. Alternatively, you can use a gem like [Simple Form](http://rubygems.org/gems/simple_form) to easily generate the associations for you like so:

```
form_for @actor do |f|
    f.collection_check_boxes :film_ids, Film.all, :id, :name
end
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew - Nice answer, makes a lot of sense. So in terms of referencing the Actors from within a film view, how would I do this?

Comment: Had a bit of a read..So in Actor class I would have an array @films?.. Thanks for adding the form part as well. Appreciated.

Comment: Do a block like: @actor.films.each do |film|

Comment: How would you go about creating the relationship in the seeds when setting up the dummy db?

Comment: It depends on how you're generating the actor and film objects. If these are static, you could add the relationships manually using either `@film.actors << actors` which will accept an array or single object and add to the association or `@film.actors = actors` which will overwrite any current associations. Read the link above for more information about the methods available to you between these models.